# Web Based WYSIWYG Editor with Photo Upload support

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, image-upload

Does anyone know what my options are for Web-based WYSIWYG editors (the type which acts like a textarea but produces HTML) are?

I need one with support for image uploads - This would be for a basic CMS that I am developing which needs to be fairly user-friendly. I can handle the server-side upload processing, but I need an upload option to be there.

A combination of CKEditor and CKFinder may have been ideal, but CKEditor seems to have been commercialised - I'm looking for something which is free/open source.

I think that this post belongs here... It was a tossup between stackoverflow and webmasters. Sorry if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) and there are several upload plugins that you can use with it, including [these here](http://sourceforge.net/search/?group_artifact_id=738747&type_of_search=artifact&group_id=103281&words=image).